# Aurora Instances are always pending status after submitted Heron Topology

Tags: scheduled-tasks, apache-storm, mesos, heron, apache-aurora

I was deployed a Twitter Heron cluster with Aurora and Mesos. The components of the cluster as following list:

1. Scheduler: Aurora scheduler
2. State Manager: zookeeper
3. Uploader: HDFS

The instances of Aurora are always pending status after I submitted the example topology named WordCountTopology. The following is a screenshot of the cluster running.

> Mesos agents:

[image]

> Aurora scheduler:

[image]

Where is the problem? Is the machine's resources in the cluster can not meet the needs the tasks of togology? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the message in the lower screen has a clear indication that you assigned not enough memory to the agents.

481 and 485mb doesn’t seem to be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again after raising the host resource configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, it looks like a resourcing issue.